# Insert Null values in SQL Server Table from ASP.NET-MVC app

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am working on ASP.NET-MVC5 app and I have tables in which I need to insert null values in some of the attribute but I am getting null value exception error. I have 5 bit fields in this table which need to update invidually

[image]

### error

[image]

### Model class

```
public class StudentProfileStatus
{
    public StudentProfileStatus() { }


    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Student ID")]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Personal Detail Status")]
    public Nullable<bool> PersonalDetailStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Detail Status")]
    public Nullable<bool> AddressDetailStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Detail Status")]
    public Nullable<bool> ContactDetailStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Course Detail Status")]
    public Nullable<bool> CourseDetailStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Emergency Contact Detail Status")]
    public Nullable<bool> EmergencyContactDetailStatus { get; set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

### Method To Update record

```
 public int UpdateStudentPersonalDetailStatus(StudentProfileStatus _studentProfileStatusModel)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var _uow = new StudentProfile_UnitOfWork())
            {
                _uow.StudentProfileStatus_Repository.InsertEntity(_studentProfileStatusModel);

                _uow.Save();

                return _studentProfileStatusModel.StudentID;
            }
        }
        catch { return 0; }
    }
```

Method calling another method (above) to update status if it create student record

### Create Student Record Method

```
public int CreateNewStudentProfile(Student _student)
    {
        try
        {
            using(var _uow = new StudentProfile_UnitOfWork())
            {
                _uow.Student_Repository.InsertEntity(_student);

                _uow.Save();

                if (_student.StudentID != 0 && _student.StudentID >0)
                {
                          var studentID = UpdateStudentPersonalDetailStatus(new StudentProfileStatus {StudentID=_student.StudentID, PersonalDetailStatus = true });

                }

                return _student.StudentID;
            }
        }
        catch { return 0; }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: provide more information about the error and what the object looks like before you invoke save

Comment: provide Student class also

Comment: yes it is null value, I have uploaded screen shot of debug! refer to my question at bottom

Comment: I just check studentID is 0... let me check!

Comment: no i am still getting error, I have uploaded screen shot in my question

Answer (score 1):

Put Student class as return type for `_uow.Student_Repository.InsertEntity(_student)`, then try this

```
var data = _uow.Student_Repository.InsertEntity(_student);
var studentID = UpdateStudentPersonalDetailStatus(new StudentProfileStatus{StudentID= data.StudentID, PersonalDetailStatus = true });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is as following;

update following code in StudentProfileStatus model class

```
    [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
    [Display(Name = "Student ID")]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
```

and add following code in student model class

```
public Student Student { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the column definitions are Nullable or not (only a suggestion)

Comment: Looks like it should be a comment. Also there's a screenshot that shows the columns are nullable in the database.